# Is there any way to get exact match in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

match_phrase in query parameter is matching the string partially. 
eg: if my match_phrase query for 'Status' is 'rejected' then it is also matching the 'rejected-qc'. like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
         {
            "match_phrase": {
               "Status": "rejected"
            }
         }
      ],
      "minimun_should_match":1
    }
  }
}
```

and the response I get for above query is two value with status as 'rejected' and 'rejected-qc', but I only want 'rejected' one - the exact match.

if I'm trying to use 'FILTER' instead it is throwing an error as following:

```
"root_cause": [
   {
     "type": "parsing_exception",
     "reason": "unknown query [filter]",
     "line": 1,
     "col": 272
   }
],
```

my payload for above error is:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
         {
            "filter": {
                "term": {
                   "Status": "rejected"
                }
            }
         }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

can anybody suggest a solution for this, that how can I match the exact string?
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do to match the exact string is to append '.keyword' after the 'status'. like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
         {
            "match_phrase": {
               "Status.keyword": "rejected"
            }
         }
      ],
      "minimun_should_match":1
    }
  }
}
```

And it will match the string exactly and not partially!

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there, simply like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "should": [
            {
                "term": {
                   "Status1": "rejected"
                }
            },
            {
                "term": {
                   "Status2": "rejected"
                }
            },
            {
                "term": {
                   "Status3": "rejected"
                }
            }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Just like 'minimum_should_match' for 'should', is there any field for filter?? If yes then please share it. I must use something like that. because there will be multiple status and i will have to match one of them.

Comment: It is giving me no data at all.

Comment: You need to change the field names to match yours of course, it's just an example if you need several matches where at least one should match

Comment: Yes i know that, but after adding 'term' key as you described it is fetching no data.

Comment: please share your mapping and a sample document you'd like to match

Comment: Thank you for you help! I found the solution, all I had to do was use 'Status.keyword' instead of 'Status'

Comment: Yep, hence why I was asking for your mapping ;-) Glad you figured it out